# R Shiny Dashboard - equivalent to navbarPage?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have made a shinydashboard in R to show all of my data, as looks better than standard shiny.

Trying to figure out how to do the equivalent of "navbarPage" in the dashboard (ie have multiple pages that show different data, rather than having all the data in different boxes on the same page).

I tried to do simply add "navbarPage(" to the code but this comes up with multiple errors)

Comment: https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/get_started.html

Answer (score 0):

The example at shiny dashboard get started page answers your question.  For your convenience, here it is.

```
    body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      title = "First tabBox",
      # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
      id = "tabset1", height = "250px",
      tabPanel("Tab1", "First tab content"),
      tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
    ),
    tabBox(
      side = "right", height = "250px",
      selected = "Tab3",
      tabPanel("Tab1", "Tab content 1"),
      tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2"),
      tabPanel("Tab3", "Note that when side=right, the tab order is reversed.")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      # Title can include an icon
      title = tagList(shiny::icon("gear"), "tabBox status"),
      tabPanel("Tab1",
        "Currently selected tab from first box:",
        verbatimTextOutput("tabset1Selected")
      ),
      tabPanel("Tab2", "Tab content 2")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    # The currently selected tab from the first box
    output$tabset1Selected <- renderText({
      input$tabset1
    })
  }
)
```